# UIButton in UIView in UITableView = can't click the button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios4, uibutton

If I add the button straight everything goes fine. I'd really like to add it inside a view and still be able to click it. Here's the code:

```
UIView *containerView =
[[[UIView alloc]
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)]
autorelease];
UIButton *footerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
footerButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);
[footerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[containerView addSubview:footerButton];
```

Comment: How do you use your `containerView`? You do `[tableView addSubview:containerView]`, or use it in table view cell? You should try to use UIButtonTypeRoundedRect and see if it is interacting or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All works fine! In your TableViewController do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)] autorelease];
    UIButton *footerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    footerButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);
    [footerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [containerView addSubview:footerButton];

    [footerButton setTitle:@"Touch me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = containerView;
}

- (void)click {
    NSLog(@"I am here!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I load it in the footerviewforsection: method

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the footer height to the height of the view you are adding to it? I had a similar problem when I returned a UIView containing a UIButton in the method viewForFooterInSection. The footer height was not large enough until I updated the heightForFooterInSection method. For example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return containerView.bounds.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `@selector(click)` looks a little odd. I would have thought your click function would like something like:

```
- (void)click:(id)sender;
```

If that's what you have then you need to add the colon `@selector(click:)` to make the signatures match.

Comment: I just changed the code to make it brief, it's obviously not like that